# How did Keitel know that Deisler was a traitor?

Tags: plot-explanation, stereo

During [*Stereo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3348102/)'s showdown *Keitel* wonders that *"Zille"* would surely not come alone. He asks *Deisler* how many men they have down there but when *Deisler* answers that there are some ten but more on their way, *Keitel* immediately identifies him as a traitor, shoots him in the head and orders *Hansen* to inform their men that there are enemies among them.

But I didn't quite understand where *Keitel* took such a fast deduction from, seeing that he must have been quite sure to just shoot him right away. But maybe I missed something, as *Keitel* seemed to have taken a look at the surveilance cameras when he talked to him. So **how did *Keitel* deduce that *Deisler* worked together with *"Zille"* (or at least with *Gaspar*)?**